# как установить reCaptcha на свой сайт

Tags: php, javascript, recaptcha

Хотелось бы использовать стандартную reCaptcha'у от гугла. Всё хорошо, на сайт встали два кода:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI"></div>

       <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

- Собственно, первое это сама формочка, а второе, подключаемый модуль.
  Апи ключ можете использовать на любом сервере, т.к. это тестовый
  ключ. Сайт сделан по MVC , всё взаимосвязано и отлично пашет. НО, что
  нужно передавать в POST запросе? Как данные приходят с этого `div`
  блока?

Кусок кода который я использовал :

---

Форма:

```
<div id="register">
    <div class="register">
        <input type="text" id="regLogin">
        <input type="email" id="regMail">
        <input type="password" id="regPassword">
        <input type="password" id="regRepeatPassword">

        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI"></div>
        <input type="button" onclick="Register();" value="зарегистрироваться">
    </div>
</div>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

Сам php код:

```
function registerAction(){

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    echo '<p><strong>' . $key.':</strong> '.$value.'</p>';
}
// ваш секретный ключ
$secret = "6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI";

// пустой ответ
$response = null;

// проверка секретного ключа
$reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha($secret);


if ($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]) 
{
    $response = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse(
    $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
    $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]);
}else{echo "error";}

    return;
}
```

Я так понял это стандартная операция для проверки этой капчи. Но что должно приходить в `POST`  и как организовать чтобы это дело приходило мне в `action`
Если всё слепить в одну страницу, то работает. Но такой выход крайне не приятен особеено в моём случае. Что передавать в POST , как его ловить, и что ловить в нём?
Вот кусок `JS` кода, который обрабатывает данные и передаёт в экшен.

JS

```
function Register(){
    var login       =   $(document.getElementById('regLogin')).val();
    var email       =   $(document.getElementById('regEmail')).val();
    var regPassword =   $(document.getElementById('regPassword')).val();
    var regPassword2=   $(document.getElementById('regPassword2')).val();
    //var reCaptcha =   $(document.getElementById('regPassword2')).val();
    var postData        = {login: login, email: email, regPassword: regPassword, regPassword2: regPassword2};

    $.ajax ({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "?controller=register&action=register",
        data: postData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
        {
            if (data['success']) {
                alert(data['message']);
            }else{
                alert(data['message']);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Как вообще организовать тут капчу?

Comment: Может вместо значений полей попробовать получить содержимое формы? Например $('form').serialize()

Comment: @DmitryKozlov , всё уже разрешилось давно.. Забыл совсем свои вопросы. Был малоопытен и не знал всех прелестей JS, сейчас всё гладко!